# D3js - Reposition tree graph in viewbox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I have used viewbox to enable my tree graph to be able to resized based on the browser window size. However, I could not position the tree to be at the center of the view box. I have tried to apply transform-translate attribute to the graph, the position remain unchanged. What attribute/changes do I have to apply to position the tree graph? Below, the first image is the current output. Image two shows the desired output. I have attached the initialisation code for the tree graph.

```
var margin = { top: 40, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 };
  var width = 700 - margin.right - margin.left;
  var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0, duration = 750;
  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .nodeSize([110,110])

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select(treeContainerDom)
    .append("div")
    .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
    .append("svg")
    //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "-50 0 1000 1000")
    //.attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+width+" "+height)
    //class to make it responsive
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
    .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5,2]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g");
```

[image: Current Output]
[image: Desired Output]